# PHP Laravel: Concat Like clause within inner join

Tags: php, laravel-5, sql-like

In php laravel i am using mysql / direct query which is shown as below:

```
$point_rewards = DB::select("select * from integral_history_listing INNER JOIN outlets ON integral_history_listing.branch_c LIKE CONCAT('%', outlets.outlet_code, '%') where outlets.merchant_id LIKE ".Auth::user()->id." ORDER BY integral_history_listing.add_time_c DESC");
```

I am able to use mysql query to get any related value to the outlet code using like clause... however i wish to write it using php laravel query builder like below :

```
$notices = DB::table('integral_history_listing')
    ->join('outlets', 'outlets.outlet_code', 'LIKE', 'integral_history_listing.branch_c')
    ->where('outlets.merchant_id', 'LIKE', Auth::user()->id)
    ->orderBy('integral_history_listing.add_time_c', 'desc')
    ->paginate(10);
```

I have try include concat within the "outlets.outlet_code" but getting module by zero error. I wish to know the proper way in using concat within inner join php laravel built query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$notices = DB::table('integral_history_listing')
->join('outlets','integral_history_listing.branch_c' , 'LIKE', DB::RAW('CONCAT("%",outlets.outlet_code,"%")'))
->where('outlets.merchant_id', 'LIKE', Auth::user()->id)
->orderBy('integral_history_listing.add_time_c', 'desc')
->paginate(10);
```

Comment: I have already use it before. It return FatalThrowableError Modulo by zero.

Comment: Still receiving the similar error message: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%outlets.outlet_code%) LIKE `integral_history_listing`.`branch_c` where `outlets' at line 1 (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `integral_history_listing` inner join `outlets` on CONCAT(%outlets.outlet_code%) LIKE `integral_history_listing`.`branch_c` where `outlets`.`merchant_id` LIKE 28)

Comment: Can you try now , missed few things before. I hope it works now.

Comment: it no longer return any error but empty result. If working it will return records. The query string as follows: [query] => select count(*) as aggregate from `integral_history_listing` inner join `outlets` on CONCAT("%",outlets.outlet_code,"%") LIKE `integral_history_listing`.`branch_c` where `outlets`.`merchant_id` LIKE ?

Comment: Were you getting any records with your Raw query?

Comment: yeah got back 9142 records with the raw query.

Comment: Change this line
`->join('outlets', DB::RAW('CONCAT("%",outlets.outlet_code,"%")'), 'LIKE', 'integral_history_listing.branch_c')`
to
`->join('outlets', 'integral_history_listing.branch_c', 'LIKE', DB::RAW('CONCAT("%",outlets.outlet_code,"%")'))`

Comment: Alright its was working right now. I just realize the mistake... Thank you for your help. Just edit your answer once more i should mark it as answer. Thanks again